# map 2 array by matching id

Tags: javascript, arrays

Array one, arr is missing qty property, but I have an arr2 which has the same id as arr, was trying to use map() of javascript function but can't get it work.

```js
var arr = [{id:1,'name':'banana'},{id:2,'name':'watermelon'}];
var arr2 = [{id:1,'qty':1},{id:1,'qty':4}];

var arr3 = arr.map(function(obj,i){
return obj.id == arr2.id;
//return obj.id
});

document.write(arr3);
```

I expect my arr3 output will be like this

```
[{id:1,'name':'banana','qty':1},{id:2,'name':'watermelon','qty':4}]
```

Comment: wait so what is the output?

Comment: @JordanHendrix updated my answer

Comment: got it, so is the second id in arr2 supposed to be 2? or is one correct?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/gmzepkL9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do a lookup inside the second array. if it was index based you could do it more easily but in your situation this is one good option:

```
var arr3 = arr.map(function(obj,i){
    var arr2match = arr2.filter( function(x){
        return x.id == obj.id;
    })[0];
    obj.qty = arr2match.qty;
    return obj;
});
```

Comment: what is the [0] in the end of filter function for?

Comment: the method Array.filter() returns an array. In this case we are assuming that there is one and only one match returning from the filter, so we assume that the result is of length 1.
Adding [0] just takes the first element of the resulting array.

Comment: one-liner version: var arr3 = arr.map(function(i){i.qty=arr2.filter(function(j){return j.id==i.id})[0].qty;return i});

Answer (score 0):

This is a little more long winded, but perhaps has more utility since it will copy all properties from the second array (not just qty).  The result is an associative array that holds a unique key for all of your id fields.

```
var arrAssoc = {};
arr.map(
    function(obj,i) {
        arrAssoc[obj.id] = obj;
    }
);
arr2.map(
    function(obj,i) {
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (key != 'id' && arrAssoc[obj.id] && obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                arrAssoc[obj.id][key] = obj[key];
            }
        }
    }
);
```

bonus round, this is the result you wanted

```
arr3 = arr.map(
    function(obj,i) {
        return arrAssoc[obj.id];
    }
);
```

Comment: fuh this is so complicated

Comment: @Jamie Jordan It's not so bad.  The first map() builds an associative array from your first array.  This makes it easier (and quicker) to look up elements by their ID.  The second map() copies all the values from the 2nd array into the matching element.  The third map builds the output you were wanting from the associative array.  If it's too complicated just use santiago arizti's answer.